# plugin's script and style enqueing not working on Thesis

Tags: plugins, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, theme-thesis

I've published a plugin on WP repository that allows some theming for Gravity Forms.

This plugin as been tested with Twenty Ten, and Twenty Eleven.
When I've tried to test it in a site that uses Thesis 1.8.5, I've found out that something wasn't working.

What this plugin does is to extend the Gravity Forms shortcode with a new action.
When this action is called, the whole form is wrapped in a div with an appropriate class, then in this case the plugin includes a skin's function.php for further customizations.

Basically the plugin checks two directories:
- `/themes` directory inside the plugin directory
- `/mgft-themes` directory inside `/wp-content`

For both directories, it lists all subdirectories and consider them as available `themes`.

When a GF shortcode has a 'theme' action and a 'themename' value, my plugin check what is available in the selected theme folder:
- It enqueue all *.js and *.css files located in theme's root
- It includes all *.php files located in theme's root

For the moment I always have a functions.php file like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style("misamee-themed-form-$theme[name]", "$theme[url]css/misamee.themed.form.$theme[name].css");
wp_enqueue_script('tooltipsy', "$theme[url]js/tooltipsy.min.js", array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script("misamee-themed-form-$theme[name]-js", "$theme[url]js/misamee.themed.form.$theme[name].js", array('jquery'));
```

This function.php is included as such (you can [grab the full code here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/misamee-gravity-forms-themes/)):

1. __construct()

   ```
   add_filter("gform_shortcode_theme", array(&$this, "misamee_themed_form_theme"), 10, 3);
   ```
2. The misamee_themed_form_theme method:

   ```
   function misamee_themed_form_theme($string, $attributes, $content)
   {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
       'title' => true,
       'description' => true,
       'id' => 0,
       'name' => '',
       'field_values' => "",
       'ajax' => false,
       'tabindex' => 1,
       'action' => 'form',
       'themename' => '',
       'cssclass' => ''
   ), $attributes));

   /** @var $themename string */
   /** @var $selectedTheme string */
   $selectedTheme = $themename;

   /** @var $id int */
   $theme = $this->misamee_themed_form_setTemplate($selectedTheme, $id);

   $additionalClasses = ($theme['name'] != '') ? " class=\"themed_form $theme[name]\"" : "";

   //$newString = str_replace('action="prettify"', 'action="form"', $string);

   $attributes['action'] = 'form';

   $formString = RGForms::parse_shortcode($attributes, $content = null);
   //$formString = do_shortcode($newString);

   if ($additionalClasses != '') {
       return "<div$additionalClasses>$formString</div>";
   }
   return $formString;
   }
   ```
3. $this->misamee_themed_form_setTemplate():

   ```
   private function misamee_themed_form_setTemplate($themeName, $formId)
   {
   $theme = $this->misamee_themed_form_getThemeByName($themeName);
   //echo "<pre>";
   if (strtolower($theme['name']) != "none") {
       if ($theme['name'] == 'default') {
           wp_enqueue_style('misamee-themed-form-css', $theme['url'] . 'css/misamee.themed.form.css');
           wp_enqueue_script('tooltipsy', $theme['url'] . 'js/tooltipsy.source.js', array('jquery'));
           wp_enqueue_script('misamee-themed-form-js', $theme['url'] . 'js/misamee.themed.form.js', array('jquery'));
       } elseif (is_dir($theme['dir'])) {
           //get all files in specified directory
           $files = glob($theme['dir'] . "/*.*");

           foreach ($files as $file) {
               $fileData = pathinfo($file);
               switch ($fileData['extension']) {
                   case 'css':
                       wp_enqueue_style($fileData['filename'], $theme['url'] . $fileData['basename']);
                       //echo "wp_enqueue_style('$fileData[filename]', '$theme[url]$fileData[basename]')\n";
                       break;
                   case 'js':
                       wp_enqueue_script($fileData['filename'], $theme['url'] . $fileData['basename']);
                       //echo "wp_enqueue_script('$fileData[filename]', '$theme[url]$fileData[basename]')\n";
                       break;
                   case 'php':
                       include($theme['dir'] . '/' . $fileData['basename']);
                       //echo "include($theme[dir]/$fileData[basename])\n";
                       break;
               }
           }
       }
       add_action("gform_field_css_class", array(&$this, "add_custom_class"), 10, 3);
   }
   return $theme;
   }
   ```

It works, at least with the default theme, but with Thesis, this php file doesn't seem to work. It doesn't raise any error: simply id doesn't do anything.

If I add a `echo 'OK';` in this file, I can see the "OK" string in the HTML, but enqueuing doesn't work.
With other themes my code works though, so I can't see how to solve this issue.

I've tried any other option, including hooking the three lines to 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_print_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'init' (I know I should user wp_print_* or init hooks, but *desperate times, desperate measures*): nothing helped.

Right now the only way to "make it work" seem to replace the `wp_enqueue_*` function with straight rendering of the `'<script ...>'` and `'<link ...>'` tags: something I really don't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've just realized that my client's theme was a custom version of Thesis with an incomprehensibly commented `wp_footer()`: as soon as I've uncommented it, the issue (obviously) disappeared.

Comment: Comment everything!  I once inherited a theme with no `wp_footer()` in footer.php.  Took hours to figure out why nothing worked.